# Handle Button click event from listview.ItemClick

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm using xamarin, and i'm trying to handle button click event from a custom listview with button inside. How can i handle my Button from Listview.ItemClick in my main Activity?

Here is my adapter

```
    class MyListViewAdapterInventory : BaseAdapter<InventoryPreviewClass>
    {
        public List<InventoryPreviewClass> mitems;
        private Context mContext;
        private int mRowLayout;
        private int[] mAlternatingColors;


        public MyListViewAdapterInventory(Context context, int rowLayout, List<InventoryPreviewClass> items)
        {
            mitems = items;
            mContext = context;
            mRowLayout = rowLayout;
            mAlternatingColors = new int[] { 0xF2F2F2, 0xbfddff };

        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return mitems.Count;
            }
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override InventoryPreviewClass this[int position]
        {
            get
            {
                return mitems[position];
            }

        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {



            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, null, false);

            }



                row.SetBackgroundColor(GetColorFromInteger(mAlternatingColors[position % mAlternatingColors.Length]));
            TextView txtInventoryID = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryID);
                txtInventoryID.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemID;
            TextView txtInventoryName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryName);
                txtInventoryName.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemName;
            TextView txtInventoryPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryPrice);
                txtInventoryPrice.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemPrice.Replace(",", ".");
            Button ExtraBtn = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasBtn);



            return row;

        }
        private Color GetColorFromInteger(int color)
        {
            return Color.Rgb(Color.GetRedComponent(color), Color.GetGreenComponent(color), Color.GetBlueComponent(color));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my activity

```
   db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
    var table = db.Query<InventoryPreviewClass>("select * from InventoryPreviewClass where CategoryID =" + Connection.CategoryID+ "");
    mItems = new List<InventoryPreviewClass>();
    foreach (var item in table)
    {

        mItems.Add(new InventoryPreviewClass() { InventoryItemID = item.InventoryItemID, InventoryItemName = item.InventoryItemName, InventoryItemPrice = item.InventoryItemPrice });


    }
    MyListViewAdapterInventory adapter = new MyListViewAdapterInventory(this, Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, mItems);
    mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
    mlistview.ItemClick += Mlistview_ItemClick;

private void Mlistview_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
  // Here i need to handle my code for button click event
}
```

I need when user is pressing button click event to opening another activity but how can i use it inside my Mlistview.ItemClick event??
[Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueo8s.jpg3)

Is it better way to handle it inside my custom adapter with Clicklistener?
Any example please?

Here is what i'm doing on click event.

```
ExtraBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                Connection.InventoryItemID = mitems[position].InventoryItemID;
                Connection.InventoryItemName = mitems[position].InventoryItemName;
                Connection.RetailPrice = mitems[position].InventoryItemPrice;
                Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(mContext, txtInventoryName.Text, ToastLength.Short);
                toast.Show();
                mContext.StartActivity(typeof(ExtrasPreviewMain));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(mContext, Convert.ToString(ex), ToastLength.Long);
                toast.Show();
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your onclick listener here :

```
Button ExtraBtn = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasBtn);
ExtraBtn.Click += (sender, e) => {
   // Perform action on click
};
```

**Update**

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
        {
          DataViewHolder holder = null;
          Button ExtraBtn ;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, null, false);
                 holder = new DataViewHolder();
                 holder.txtInventoryID = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryID);         
                 holder.txtInventoryName = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryName);   
                 holder.txtInventoryPrice = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryPrice);
                 ExtraBtn = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasBtn);
                 ExtraBtn.Click += (sender, e) => {
                    // Perform action on click
                   }; 
                    convertView.Tag = holder;
                  ExtraBtn.Tag = position;
            } else {
                ExtraBtn = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.lr_deleteBtn);
                 holder = convertView.Tag as DataViewHolder;
                 ExtraBtn.Tag = position;
            }
           convertView.SetBackgroundColor(GetColorFromInteger(mAlternatingColors[position % mAlternatingColors.Length]));
           holder.txtInventoryID.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemID;
           holder.txtInventoryName.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemName;
           holder.txtInventoryPrice.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemPrice.Replace(",", ".");

            return convertView;

        }

     public class DataViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView txtInventoryID { get; set; }
    public TextView txtInventoryName { get; set; }
    public TextView txtInventoryPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that every time i scolling up or down(refreshing adapter) my listview it perform always my button click action.Example if you will put a toast message inside button click and you scroll down-up twice. then it will show you the toast message two times.Is there any way which i can preventing that? then i'm ok

Comment: Hmm did you try to use:  Button ExtraBtn = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasBtn); and register the click listener  inside the if (row == null){ ...    }

Comment: Should also place button click event inside my if(row == null)??

Comment: The problem in this case is that i'm taking wrong other elements which i use. example if i will call toast with another item is not the write one   Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(mContext, mitems[position].InventoryItemName, ToastLength.Short);
                        toast.Show();Look my adapter and tell me if i must move in other  place mitems. If i will place them inside if(row==null) then every time i'm scrolling up and down i'm getting wrong item order

Comment: The only way that works is to delete if(row==null) but i dont know if i will have problem with this later

Comment: ExtraBtn.Click deosnt exist in current context

Comment: sorry I continue editing my answer, wait me 5 minutes

Comment: Np thank you for all your effort.What if i will remove permenately if(row==null)??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159528/discussion-between-user8978978-and-diegoveloper).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is +=, use = instead.

```
mlistview.ItemClick += Mlistview_ItemClick;
```

change to:

```
mlistview.ItemClick = Mlistview_ItemClick;
```

Comment: Thank you for the approach but my question is how can i handle button event click (from custom listivew) in my mlistview.itemclick

Comment: @user8978978 where you init your extra button you need to set the button's onclick listener

Comment: Exactly i think that is what i'm looking for! First should i place it inside adapter or in my activity. And also if could you write me an example pls

Comment: @user8978978 it is depend on you requests what you want to do inside this listener. you can create listener inside of getView or if it is something general so u can create listener as a member of object snd simply call set listener inside of getView. explain what you want to do in onclick. which data to pass to the new activity. Implementation of listener must be inside of adapter and not in activity

Comment: @user8978978 your implementation seems ok. i cant to give you example. im not strong in xamarin. but thus implementation is what you need inside getView. because you are using the data from list item to pass to the activity

Comment: need to put this listener i side your custom adapter i side of getView method aftee findview of the button